# how to make a text file for logging in c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging

here is my code for logging

```
System.IO.FileInfo perf = new System.IO.FileInfo(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/perf.log"));

perf.IsReadOnly = false;
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(perf.ToString(), true);

sw.WriteLine(logString);
sw.Flush();
sw.Close();
```

all i want to do is

```
if(!File.Exists)
{
   //what should i write here to create a text file?
}
else
{
   //do the upper code logic
}
```

thank you in advance

Comment: every time i do File.Create(Path), it gives me exception that the file is bieng used by another process.

Comment: please please dont cast negative votes.

Comment: Tip for the future - make sure the clear explaination about why your posted code isn't working and what you want to achieve is posted clearly in your original question, not as a comment. If the question is clear, we can see you have made efforts to code the solution yourself, and you clearly state what is wrong and what you want to achieve, you won't get downvotes

Comment: No worries, StackOverflow isn't that scary, as long as you know the basics. You show good etiquette already, so welcome aboard!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

do it like this

```
if (!File.Exists("yourfilePath"))
     File.Create("yourfilePath");

using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("yourFilePath", true))
{
    sw.WriteLine("logString");        
}
```

Comment: @user3458227 You should probably mark it as answered if it solved your problem. :)